# How to get a jQuery UI Autocomplete working

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I know, there's about 20 questions here that mention jQuery UI Autocomplete. I've read a bunch and I'm still stuck...

I am trying to learn how to implement jQuery UI's Autocomplete feature and I'm working off of [this tutorial](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/) since it seems closest to my needs and how I need to handle the PHP/MySQL end.

I've been going back and forth between that tut and the documentation and I can't seem to get it working.

I'm trying to set up (what I think is) a simple autocomplete, getting a single field from a db query.

Here's the jQuery code I have at the moment:

```
$('input.urlSearch').autocomplete({
    source: '../scripts/branchAdmin.php',
    minLength: 3
});
```

And here's the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $searchTerm = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $fetch = mysqli_query("SELECT url FROM branches WHERE url LIKE '%" . $searchTerm . "%'");
    $returnArr = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rowArr['url'] = $row['url'];

        array_push($returnArr,$rowArr);
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Here's the HTML for the textbox

```
<td id="newBranchUrl" class="branchData">
    <input type="text" id="txtNewBranchUrl" class="urlSearch" />
</td>
```

The "url" field in the query is really a short string of states and in the case of two-word states (e.g. North Carolina) there's a dash between the words.

When I start typing in the textbox nothing happens - whether I type test I know is or is not in the db. I'm not seeing any network activity in the console, either (using Chrome).

The tut sure makes it *look* simple! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is wrong? Dont you get a reply? Nothing appears but there is a response. Please tell us the error.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that. Nothing's happening. I start typing and no suggestion pops up - no network activity in the console is indicated, either. Question has been updated with this info.

Comment: please post your html. As this is REALLY easy and should work instant. i did just this: http://jsfiddle.net/btkZf/ and it works as expected.

Comment: I added the HTML to the question (after the PHP code), but I don't see how that's going to add any valuable info, as it's a simple textbox in a td tag.

Comment: @JulianHille, also, I checked out your jsFiddle and, though that seems to work in terms of the textbox and js, I noticed that you didn't include a library (it's using pure JS). So when I added jQuery 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2, the "No search results" didn't show up. Also, I'm not sure that your jsFiddle is a very good comparison, as it's not really connecting to a PHP script that will return results...

Comment: Please also put in the head how you put in the jquery libs.

Comment: @JulianHille, The rest of my (rather extensive) .js file is loaded with jQuery and it all works fine.

Comment: the fiddle i postet does include the necessary js AND is doing the callback. So like you told you dont see any network activity, in the fiddle i do. There seems to be somethings wrong on your side. The problem is, with the infos you gave, the problem is unsolvable. Because what you give is totally working. So the problem needs to be somewhere else. What is why i asked for your headers.